# How to display save pdf window in mdPDF ?

Tags: php

How i can show "save as" window, instead of showing generated PDF file (from mdPDF plugin) in browser window ? I try to set- `$mpdf->Output($_SESSION['pdf_filename'].'.pdf', 'F');`
but its just save the file on folder, not giving me a link.

Comment: output an appropriate "force download" header , e.g. "content-type: application/octet-stream". you cannot override a user's browser configuration. if they specified to save a pdf automatically, there's nothing you can do to override that, other than NOT sending a "PDF", by lying about its mime type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using [this mPDF](https://mpdf.github.io/), correct? (*Link is for the github page dedicated to the project.*)

If so, I believe you need to be using the *`D`* parameter for the `Output(...)` call, not the *`F`* parameter. So that would change your output call to the following:

```
$mpdf->Output($_SESSION['pdf_filename'].'.pdf', 'D');
```

According to [the documentation page about the Output function](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/output.html), the *D* parameter does the following:

> D: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by $filename.

Comment: Thank you! It exactly what i need for.